# Multiple definition of main for zlib

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I am trying to compile my cocos2d-x project, but when I run the build_native.sh I get this error:

```
/Users/default/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/3rdParty/zlib-1.2.3/minigzip.o: multiple definition of 'main'
/Users/default/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/3rdParty/zlib-1.2.3/example.o: previous definition here
/Users/default/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/tiff.a(mkg3states.o): multiple definition of 'main'
/Users/default/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/3rdParty/zlib-1.2.3/example.o: previous definition here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory //.....
```

I can build the project without zlib, but I need it.

**EDIT**:

After removing example.c, I get this:

```
/Users/default/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/tiff.a(mkg3states.o): multiple definition of 'main'
/Users/default/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/3rdParty/zlib-1.2.3/minigzip.o: previous definition here
```

Can I exclude libtiff from cocos2d or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `minigzip` and `example` source code files contain a `main()` function. Remove the one you don't need. I'm guessing it's in `example`.

Comment: We checked and cleaned out the make files. It works now. Thanks for the help!